# Failed to open page: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-server

I am running Zend Server on my Mac, working on a local PHP (Zend Framework) project. I've never come across this problem before, but there are certain lines in my code that trigger an error in my Safari console when I load the page:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)

The Apache error log has this:

> [notice] child pid 17822 exit signal Bus error (10)

However, by changing little things about the code that shouldn't matter (commenting out lines, rearranging lines, changing the contents of a string), it randomly works (or doesn't work). The same code works fine on my co-worker's MAMP server and on our Ubuntu dev server.

I'm totally stuck. I am only assuming that there is some sort of bug in Zend Server that is causing this issue. Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a result of Safari holding too much local data for the site in question and failing to deal with that correctly. I use archive.org *a lot* so I had lots of LocalStorage and Cookie data for that site. The fact that this data is only in my main browser Safari and not in any of my other browsers explains why they could browse the site just fine.

So, the solution:

1. Go into Safari > Preferences > Privacy
2. Search for the affected domain name (for me this was "archive.org")
3. Click Remove
4. The problem goes away!

Here's a video showing the problem before and after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqww1.jpg